# How should I store file history in a MySQl data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a web app with JS and PHP where users can edit a file similar to a text editor such as notepad. I've decided to use a database to store these files. One of the primary functions of a text editor is the file history (Undo and Redo).

I would like to store this on the server and not just on the client. This will allow for history, even after the page is refreshed. In my database, I'm trying to keep every cell to a single value as recommended, instead of using JSON. My first thought is to just create a bunch of history cells for each version. This seems unnecessarily complicated, not to mention that it could get large exponentially faster.

I then thought I could store the past 50 or so versions on the client and then combine every 5 when it goes to the server to condense it to just 10 versions. That's still 10x the file size for something that most likely isn't going to get used.

Is there a better way to structure the database so that my file could be smaller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes as small compared to the document size, you can save a lot of storage by just storing the change itself (the difference between the before and after documents).

Storing your Undo/Redo this way is somewhat similar to storing events, so you can look into Event Sourcing for ideas how to do it efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there are file storage constraints or there is a performance requirement for finding a diff of a file, it is usually easier to store the entire file rather than just the diffs.  With image and media files, this is a requirement, so you won't need to change code to handle different file types.  These days, you simply shouldn't worry about storage size unless you know from previous experience that it's going to be a problem.

Having every the full file of every version eliminates the need to recreate a particular version of a file every time you need it.  It also eliminates any errors that may occur in rebuilding the process because diffs aren't always perfect and your document may "drift" over many many versions.  Doing undo/redo is trivial because you just call up the previous version and make it the latest.  Storing the files in the database itself can have allow you to do full text searching as most databases have that now, but don't store all the versions in a single row as searching for results becomes highly problematic.

You could also use a proper open source platform with versioning asset management built-in like [TACTIC](http://tactic.southpawtech.com) which already has these features built in and you won't have to build it from scratch.  You can look at the source code to see how it's done at [GitHub](https://github.com/Southpaw-TACTIC/TACTIC)

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose of storing is to store during a refresh why not use [local storage](https://javascript.info/localstorage) instead? That will be more responsive than server storage.

And for server side storage wouldn't it be more feasible to use a nosql db like mongodb to avoid translating back and forth to JSON?

Comment: I think that I am actually going to do that, just with all the uncondensed versions. I still would like there to be some history on the server if the file is opened from another browser though.